# Content Security Policy Error in MERN App (nodemailer)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I am developing MERN App, a Blogify. I created a sign up and sign in. Now I create the "Forgot Password" action with nodemailer.

I can send mail successfully both in development environment and production environment. When I click on the link received by mail in the development environment, it works successfully, but when I click on it in the production environment, the following error occurs.

Incoming mail example: (..link/forgot-password/:userId/:token)

Please follow the link to reset your password -> https://codermocha.herokuapp.com/forgot-password/6196521181b12d4804d639b5/69849684469c15339328e0744fc6de0a6db993ce83b88838720e927c1ca5a7bf

[Error page after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aQe3.png)

**Error Message:** Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com wss://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-JUCCMgPUsmi3ZsiQj4jAd7Uy7nrvEJzzDwDynfMpvuM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

**Password Controller**

```
export const passwordResetRequest = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  if (!email)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Please enter an email!" });

  const user = await User.findOne(req.body);
  if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ message: "User does not exist!" });

  const token = await Token.findOne({ userId: user._id });
  if (!token) {
    token = await new Token({
      userId: user._id,
      token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
    }).save();
  }

  const link = `${process.env.BASE_URL}${user._id}/${token.token}`;
  await sendEmail(user.email, "Password Reset", link);

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ message: "Password reset link sent to your email account" });
});

export const passwordReset = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { newPassword, confirmPassword } = req.body;
  const { userId, token } = req.params;
  if (!newPassword || !confirmPassword)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Please check your fileds!" });

  const user = await User.findById({ _id: userId });
  if (!user)
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid link or expired" });

  const tokenDb = await Token.findOne({ userId: user._id, token });
  if (!tokenDb)
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid link or expired" });

  user.password = newPassword;
  await user.save();
  await tokenDb.delete();

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Password reset is successfull." });
});
```

**Send Mail Helper Function**

```
const sendEmail = async (email, subject, text) => {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.HOST,
      service: process.env.SERVICE,
      port: 587,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.USER,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: process.env.USER,
      to: email,
      subject,
      text: `Please follow the link to reset your password -> ${text}`,
    });

    console.log("Email başarıyla gönderildi");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in a different way.

The folder structure in the application was nested. I was running both front-end and back-end together using the Concurrently package. After changing the folder structure, my problem was solved.

I placed the front-end and back-end in separate folders and deployed them separately.

```
**Before**
-config
-models
-controllers
-routers
-front-end
 ..react folders and files
-index.js

**After**
-back-end
 ..node.js folders and files
-front-end
 ..react folders and files
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive tells that the style you are applying to the displayed page is not from a validated source. Only styles that have the source as(i.e. are coming from) https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com or wss://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com will be allowed to be used. (Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src#examples)

Please check the Content-Security-Policy in your response headers and if you can modify them. You can also add the SHA given in the error to your CSP header something like this -

```
style-src :  'https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com' 'wss://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com' 'sha256-JUCCMgPUsmi3ZsiQj4jAd7Uy7nrvEJzzDwDynfMpvuM'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've been trying since yesterday but I still can't figure out how to do it. This is the first time I've encountered this error, so I'm having a little trouble understanding it. I've added the code starting with "style-src" to the meta tag in various ways, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Hey, so you have to add all the SHAs that you are getting in the error message. I see that you are getting 7 error statements with SHAs, so add all the 7 SHAs to your style-src tag (removing the last = signs for each SHA while adding).
Also, it is not recommended, but have you tried with style-src : 'unsafe-inline' ?

Comment: Hello, I've tried so many combinations and I'm still searching but either it didn't work or the styles in the app didn't work. :( By the way I am sorry for late reply.

Comment: Ohkay..I suggest something like this -
style-src : 'self' 'unsafe-inline'

Comment: It didn't work :( Again, thank you for your interest. <3